# Normal vector to surfaces in 3D space verification

Tags: proof-verification, vectors, 3d, surfaces

Book A claims that for $ z=f(x,y)$ , the standard normal to the surface of the graph z is given the vector $<-\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}},-\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}},1>$. In what direction does $ <-\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}},-\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}},1>$ point? Does $ <-\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}},-\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}},1>$ point in the positive $ z$ -axis or negative z-axis?

Book B claims that for the graph of z, $<\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}},\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}},1>$ is the standard normal to the graph $ z=f(x,y)$. In what direction does the vector $<\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}},\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}},1>$ which is similar to a ray point?

Book A claims that the outward normal to a sphere is $ (-a^2sin(\phi)) (sin(\phi)cos(\theta),sin(\phi)sin(\theta),cos(\phi))$

Book B claims that the outward normal to a sphere is $ (a^2sin(\phi)) (sin(\phi)cos(\theta),sin(\phi)sin(\theta),cos(\phi))$

Is book A or B right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A normal vector can be found by taking a cross product of a pair of vectors that are tangent to the surface. Any pair will do as long as they are not parallel/anti-parallel to each other.

For a small $\delta$, one such pair of vectors is 
$$
u = \begin{pmatrix}
\delta \\0 \\ \delta \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
\textrm{and}
\qquad
v = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\\delta \\ \delta \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

We can take cross product of these two vectors to be either $u \times v$ or from $v \times u$. Either of these will lead to a valid normal. The rule for cross product is that $v \times u = - (u \times v)$ so the two normals will point in opposite directions. This makes sense because we are considering the surface to be locally like a flat plane.

$$
u \times v
=
\begin{pmatrix}
- \delta^2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
\\
- \delta^2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
\\
\delta^2
\end{pmatrix}
=
\delta^2 
\begin{pmatrix}
-  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
\\
-  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which gives the vector $\left(- \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}, 1\right)^T$ as pointing in the normal direction.

The rule for cross product  that $v \times u = - u \times v$ which means that $\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}, -1\right)^T$ is also in the  normal direction.

If the surface is closed, some texts describe these normals as 'inward' and 'outward'.
For a function depending on $z$, just use the dot product to see which of these  directions is closer to the direction of the positive $z$ axis.

Based on the above, book B looks incorrect to me.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for part 1: What's the dot product with a unit vector in the positive $z$ direction? (Note: you've written the normal wrong -- check those variables!)

Hint for part 2: What you've written is certainly incorrect. If you changed the final "$1$" to a "$-1$", it'd be better.

As to which is "standard", it depends on your book, mostly, but I'd say that the first is favored, for if you write
$$
F(x, y) = (x, y, f(x, y)), 
$$
which is a pretty natural thing to do, 
then $F$ is a natural parameterization of the surface, and the standard orientation of the $xy$-plane ($x$ first, $y$ second) then transforms, via the differential of $F$, to the BookA version.

(This is an answer to the version of the question that reads as shown below (or, to be honest, the previous one). It's changed 4 times as I was writing the answer, and I'm not willing to wait for it to stabilize.)

> Book A claims that for $ z=f(x,y)$ , the standard normal to the surface of the graph z is given the vector $<-\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}},-\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}},1>$. In what direction does $ <-\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}},-\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}},1>$ point? Does $ <-\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}},-\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}},1>$ point in the positive $ z$ -axis or negative z-axis?
>
> Book B claims that for the graph of z, $<\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}},\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}},1>$ is the standard normal to the graph $ z=f(x,y)$. In what direction does the vector $<\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}},\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}},1>$ which is similar to a ray point?
>
> Book A claims that the outward normal to a sphere is $ (-a^2sin(\phi)) (sin(\phi)cos(\theta),sin(\phi)sin(\theta),cos(\phi))$
>
> Book B claims that the outward normal to a sphere is $ (a^2sin(\phi)) (sin(\phi)cos(\theta),sin(\phi)sin(\theta),cos(\phi))$
>
> Is book A or B right?

Comment: please check updated question.

Comment: I just made another edit.